# Laravel routing shows only one ID in URL even if that ID doesn't exist in the table

Tags: php, laravel, url, controller, routes

In my sidebar I have list od default cities. When I click on each city I get some data for that city from certain API. That part works. In the same sidebar I also have list od favorite cities which registered users can add to that list as much as they want to, and later on they can get some data for their favorite cities by just clicking on them. Sounds easy, but this part doesn't work. The problem is that Laravel routing system gets only one ID from my favorites table for each favorite city in the list.

This is the route:

```
Route::get('/favorites/{id}/', 'FavoriteController@show')->name('showFavoriteWeather');
```

This is the controller:

```
    public function show($id){

            $favorite_city = Favorite::find($id);

            // dd($favorite_city);

            $api_key = "";  
            $url = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/group?id=$favorite_city->city_id&units=metric&appid=$api_key"; 
            $ch = curl_init($url);
            curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $json_response = curl_exec($ch);

            $data = json_decode($json_response, true);

            // dd($data);

            return view('showFavoriteWeather', compact('data'));
        }
```

Favorite cities are listed fine in the sidebar but the URL for each link is the same: **localhost:8000/favorites/3**

The ID is always **3** and the tricky part is that I actually don't have anything in my favorites table with that ID. I deleted that row a day ago. So my question is why is only ID 3 showing in URL's for my favorite cities? Database I'm using is MySQL.

In addition to this, when I manually change ID **3** in URL to **1** or **2** or any other that I have in my database it all works fine - I get the data I want for the city I choose.

The code in the blade that assembles links that don't work goes like this:

```
<ul>
@foreach ($favorites as $key => $favorite)               
    <li><a href="{{ route('showFavoriteWeather', $id) }}">{{ $favorite->city_name }}</a></li>  
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: try these on your terminal `php artisan view:clear` `php arisan cache:clear` `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: I did. It doesn't work. It's all the same nevertheless

Comment: If your problem is your list of links showing the same url you should be posting the code/blade that assembles those links.

Comment: Could you also provide the controller method associated with this blade ? I believe that you didn't define the **$id** variable there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your href should be this :

```
<a href="{{ route('showFavoriteWeather', $favorite->id) }}">
```

you're just passing in `$id` the way you have it, you need to grab the id of the actual iterated object of the foreach loop.